# ELO Rating as a sorting algorithm

Tags: probability, statistics, sorting

Let $N$ be the number of players each with a *true* rating $R_i$, where $i \in \{1,2,...,N\}$. Two players, $A$ and $B$, are selected at random and made to play a game. Let their *current* ratings be $R_A$ and $R_B$, respectively. We use the ELO rating system to calculate the expectation of a player to win the game as

$$E_A = \frac{1}{1 + 10^{(R_B - R_A)/400}}, \\
E_B = \frac{1}{1 + 10^{(R_A - R_B)/400}}.$$

Their new ratings are given by the expressions

$$R'_A = R_A + K(S_A - E_A),\\
R'_B = R_B + K(S_B - E_B).$$

If $A/B$ wins, $S_{A/B} = 1$. If $A/B$ loses, $S_{A/B} = 0$. $K$ is a constant (say 32). If each of these $N$ players start with a *base* rating of 1400, what order of games are required for the players to arrive at an accurate ranking? More generally, how does ELO rating serve as a sorting algorithm?

Comment: What is an "accurate rating" (in the world of only two players playing only themselves repeatedly)?

Comment: The question isn't well-defined because there are three outcomes and we only know the mean, so we don't know the probabilities of the three outcomes. In the one extreme, the players might never draw; in the other extreme, one of the players might never win. It may be that the number of games required to equilibrate the ratings would be similar, but this is not immediately obvious.

Comment: @dan_fulea: The question isn't clear in this regard, but it would make sense to ask how long it takes to equilibrate the **difference** between their two ratings.

Comment: @squeak: Rating changes are usually rounded to integer values -- are you omitting that to simplify the problem? Also, if you don't round, you need to specify how precisely you want to approximate the rating, since the expected rating will never actually reach the true rating. You could either specify a target precision, or require that the difference between the expected rating and the true rating be less than some number of standard deviations of the rating.

Comment: @joriki: I agree the question isn't well defined, largely because I am not sure how to do so. Intuitively it makes sense that as more games are played, the *current* ratings will tend to the *true* ratings. Is there a way to quantify how close the *current* ratings will be to their *true* rating? If we only talk about win/loss, the expected value of $S_A$ should be the $E_A$ computed with the *true* rating. More generally, how does ELO rating work as a sorting algorithm?

Comment: Similar question: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/900812/calculating-the-average-number-of-games-required-to-reach-a-theoretical-true-elo

Answer (score 0):

As the comments have noted, this question isn't quite well specified, so allow me to make a few specifications to the problem.

Let's say that there is a positive lower bound $\epsilon$ on the differences between true Elo scores. This is convenient because otherwise, it might take an arbitrarily long time to statistically determine which of two players is better, even if every game played were between them.

Unfortunately, even with this assumption, it seems it is not the case that the probability that the ratings are correctly sorted approaches one as the number of games played increases. Even if all the players scores are exactly correct at some point, if we play further games, there is a non-zero chance that one player will win disproportionately to how often they are expected to, and the sorting could change.

Instead, I think it's interesting to consider another approach, where instead of tracking and updating an estimate of a players scores, we instead simply estimate the sorted list of players at any given time, perhaps by a maximum likelihood estimate of the Elo scores, or some other function of the records of each player.

In the usual lower bound on the runtime of sorting algorithms, we observe that each comparison gives us 1 bit of information about the true order, and that this means at least $O(\log_2 n!) = O(n \log n)$ comparisons are necessary to correctly sort the list. In our scenario, each game gives less than 1 bit, so at least $O(n \log n)$ games will still be necessary to achieve any constant probability of correctness.

On the other hand, there are algorithms that sort in $n \log n$ time. If we imagine playing $k_{\epsilon, n, p}$ games between a pair of players whenever we would compare them, where $k_{\epsilon, n, p}$ is large enough to guarantee a less than $\frac{p}{n \log n}$ chance that the worse player wins more often, then we would have probability less than $p$ of any of the comparisons getting it wrong. Thus, we could get we could sort the players accurately in $O(k_{\epsilon, n, p} n \log n)$. Keeping $\epsilon, p$ constant, $k$ should be roughly quadratic in $n$, so I bet you could sort the players in $\tilde{O}(n^3)$ games, maybe less with something more clever.